# Updating a field in a table for a logged in user more than once

Tags: php, mysql, database, field

I am trying to update a field within a table in my database, so that when the user enters in data, perhaps in a form, it will save to the database field which i can the retrieve and display on the page for the next time they sign in, so this would have to be specific to my logged in user. The user will need to be able to do this whenever they want and the data would have to be inputed into the same field All help is appreciated.

Comment: user must be enter username and password to log-in. Save your data in the database with username. When user log-in, fetch data on the basis of username and show

Comment: I have the login set up, i just want the user to be able to enter data such as wedding to do lists, as this is what the site is about so i want it then to save into a field within the ser table which i have already created but cant seem to get the code.

Comment: You are essentially asking about the fundamentals of PHP and SQL - how to update a database based on form entries. Do some tutorials or read a book and you will learn how to do this and learn something on the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this will be to create a new table that has as it foreign key the user id. For a user table that looks like this.

Table Name: Users

Fields:

- id : int
- username : varchar
- password : varchar

Next you will need to create a new table for your todo items. The table will look something like this below.

Table Name: todos

Fields:

- id : int
- users_id : int
- item : varchar
- data : timestamp

This will allow you todo a join statement on the two tables, or if you have the user id you can always include a where statement to query the table directly.

I personally have not watched this, but it might be helpful. http://youtu.be/RGx0q_ZqYeY